# Class with multiple IDisposable fields

Tags: c#

Is there best practice to implement IDisposable class DisposableClass1 that contains several IDisposable fields of type DisposableClass2 and where:

1. Possible exceptions in constructor DisposableClass2
2. Possible exceptions in Dispose method of DisposableClass2
3. We can't modify DisposableClass2

I wrote some code to show situation, but for me it looks ugly. Is there a way to improve it?

```
public class DisposableClass1 : IDisposable
{
    private List<DisposableClass2> DFields;

    public DisposableClass1()
    {
        DFields = new List<DisposableClass2>();
        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                DFields.Add(new DisposableClass2());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Dispose(throwException: false);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(throwException: true);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool throwException)
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        foreach (var f in DFields)
        {
            try
            {
                f.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                exceptions.Add(e);
            }
        }

        if (exceptions.Count > 0 && throwException)
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
}

// We can't modify this class
public class DisposableClass2 : IDisposable
{
    public DisposableClass2()
    {
        // May throw exception.
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // May throw exception.
    }

    ~DisposableClass2()
    {
        // May throw exception.
    }
}
```

Comment: An exception in the constructor is not an issue, the field you use won't be initialized.  An exception in Dispose() is off the table as a practical concern, you either have to fix that class so it cannot throw or you must never catch it.  There is nothing you can do to pretend it did not happen and a failing finalizer is a very nasty problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Failing in a constructor *is* an issue because there are multiple disposable resources.  If one of them fails all of the other successfully created instances need to be cleaned up, and the dispose method of the OP's class won't run because the constructor never completed.  The same issue is a concern in the dispose method; an error cleaning up one object can't stop you from cleaning up the others.  The type has no finializer, so that's not a concern at all, only user code calling dispose is relevant.

Comment: Thanks for remarks. I did some fixes in code. For sure DisposableClass2 should have finializer, I just drop it to make code smaller. But I still want to free resources as soon as possible if I got Exception in constructor or dispose mthod, I don't want to wait GarbageCollector to process. Is it ok now, or can I do something better?